# How can I exit a while loop at any time during the loop?

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I have a python program that loops through some GPIO commands. How can I break the loop at any time during the loop by pressing the Enter key. So far I have this...

```
import sys
import select
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)

i = 0
while True:
     os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
     print "I'm doing stuff. Press Enter to stop me!"
     print i
     GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
     time.sleep(1)
     GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
     time.sleep(1)
     GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
     time.sleep(1)
     GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
     time.sleep(1)
     if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
         line = raw_input()
         break
     i += 1
```

This works but once pressing Enter to break the loop I have to wait until the GPIO.output commands have finished before the loop will break. I want it to break immediately.

Comment: This is not really a Pi question.  Check more often, or interrupt by pressing control C.

Comment: Try using subprocess or a multi-tasking module to run the GPIO data for you. The main problem is the time.sleep() which will stop until its over.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the length of the `time.sleep()` to the length of time you are willing to wait between pressing Enter and breaking out of the loop. `time.sleep()` will take a floating point input, so you can specify times like 0.1s if necessary.

If you need the loop to break absolutely immediately, you will probably need a separate dedicated process to watch the keyboard. If breaking before the next change in GPIO level is sufficient, try reducing the length of the loop, so there is only one `time.sleep()` per check of the keyboard, and using logic to decide what to do with the GPIO each time, like so:

```
import sys
import select
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)

i = 0
toggle = False

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
print "I'm doing stuff. Press Enter to stop me!"
while True:
    print i
    if toggle:
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
    else:
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
    if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
        line = raw_input()
        break
    i += 1
    toggle = not toggle
```

If you need to be able to break out of the loop faster than you are toggling the GPIO, then use a shorter sleep and add some more logic to count the number of loops between changes of the GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114292/break-interrupt-a-time-sleep-in-python

Also you might want to consider the hints given in the comments section.